# Parameter to disable Sling filter in AEM

Tags: aem, sling, sling-models

I have created a sling filter. Below is a snippet -

```
@SlingFilter(label = "My filter", description = "Myfilter", metatype = true, generateComponent = true, generateService = true, order = 0, scope = SlingFilterScope.INCLUDE)

public class SlingInoFilter implements Filter { 
}
```

When I deploy my code, I want this filter to be deployed but in a disabled state. Is this achievable?

Comment: Unsure of having it disabled, but you can have a [Sling Feature Flag](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/featureflags.html) to check whether the filter needs to execute or not. Sample implementation blogpost - https://www.albinsblog.com/2020/08/sling-feature-flags-for-continuous-integration-in-aem-feature-toggles-in-aem.html#.X0crfGziuUk

Comment: @rakhi4110 How about providing an invalid value to the scope as mentioned here - https://techrevel.blog/2019/07/04/ds-annotations-sling-filter/ 
Not sure if its the best practice

Comment: I don't think deploying a code which is wrong on purpose makes since. Because if you want to enable it again you need to do a full deployment for it to use the right scope. Having feature flags provides you the ability to turn it on or off using OSGi configuration avoiding deployments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it by using ACS commons component disabler:
https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/osgi-disablers/component-disabler/index.html